# Loop not faster despite looping through half as many iterations?

Tags: c++, loops, primes

I wrote a program that searches for primes:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <chrono>

typedef std::chrono::high_resolution_clock Clock;
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int p;
    int x = 1;
    int b;
    int a[1000000];
    bool n = false;
    a[0] = 2;
    a[1] = 3;

    auto t1 = Clock::now();

    ofstream outfile;
    outfile.open("p.txt");

    for (p = 3; p < 7500000; p = p + 2)
    {
        for (b = 0; b <= x && n == 0; b++)
        {
            if (p % a[b / 2] == 0)
            {
                n = true;
            }
        }
        if (n == false)
        {
            cout << p << endl;
            outfile << p << endl;
            x++;
            a[x] = p;
        }
        else
        {
            n = false;
        }
    }

    auto t2 = Clock::now();
    std::cout
        << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(t2 - t1).count()
        << " nanoseconds" << std::endl;
    outfile.close();
}
```

Initially for the loop increment I had `p++`, but I changed that to `p=p+2` because all primes essentially are odd and even numbers don't need to be checked. Problem is when I benchmarked this, there was no difference in speed between the old and new code. So what is the bottleneck in the process, if checking all the numbers is no different than checking half? And is there a better way to approach this?

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but get in the habit of initializing objects when you create them, rather than updating them later. In particular, replace `ofstream outfile; outfile.open("p.txt");` with `ofstream outfile("p.txt");`. And you don't need `outfile.close();` -- the destructor will do that.

Comment: How are you doing the benchmarks?

Comment: please fix the indentation. I felt like on a rollercoaster reading this.

Comment: also, silly question, you are compiling with optimisations turned on yes?

Comment: Another style suggestion: don't define variables until they are needed. For example, `int p; ... for (p = 3; ...' can be replaced by `for (int p - 3; ...`.

Comment: @GBlodgett I just copy pasted some code from online that takes a measure of the time before starting all the loop stuff and after everything's done, subtracts one from the other, and thus gives the time it took to run the program.

Comment: One this is that you include file writing in your loop, at the best of times writing to a file can vary very much depending on what other processes are doing on the PC, that combined with an optimizing compiler and you may get varying results.

Comment: From https://primes.utm.edu/howmany.html, it will take more than 10,000,000 numbers (and less than 100,000,000) to find the first million primes.  So how did you choose  "p<7500000"?  (if I'm reading your code correctly)

Comment: @2785528 cuz a larger number gave me a segfault for some reason. Also I'm just testing this rn, and don't want to wait like 15 min every time I run this

Comment: @J.Doe: Good answer.   As to your segfault, maybe consider this:  "int a[1000000]" allocates 4 (or 8) million bytes (depending on your compiler and os).  On Ubuntu, the default stack size (where automatic memory resides) is 8 million bytes, so the bigger int size would overwhelm the default stack.  Instead of an array, I recommend you use std::vector().  It uses only 24 bytes of automatic memory, regardless of sizeof(int) or number of elements (i.e. data is in dynamic memory, which you probably have much more of.)

Comment: @2785528 Ok, that's cool, I'll try that. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's this line:

```
for(b=0; b<=x && n==0; b++)
```

Once `n=true;` executes, the `b` loop exits because of the `&& n==0` condition. This happens with the very first test: every even number is divisible by two, which is `a[0]`. So for even numbers (that you include if you use `p++` instead of `p=p+2`) the inner loop is very quick, much quicker than for a typical odd number. This explains why including them makes so little difference.

Comment: yeah, kinda obvious if you think about it, haha. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your outer loop skips half the numbers. But your inner loop tests every number twice. So you give up all your gains.

If you don't see that your inner loop does everything twice, consider that `a[b/2]` is the same when `b` is 1 as it is when `b` is 0.

Comment: This does not explain why *not* skipping half the numbers would not double the time.

Comment: Noted, will fix that. Thanks.

Comment: It actually explains why it takes *more* than double the time. Skipping the even numbers is a small gain. Processing the actual hard work twice probably costs more than that. You answered the question he asked. I explained why his code is much slower than it should be. ;)